# Function only partially executing

Tags: javascript, function

I guess I'm a beginner at javascript and as the title suggests, my function won't fully execute.

```
function showBorder2(classid){

            var first2 = document.getElementById("swordsmanIcon");
            var second2 = document.getElementById("marksmanIcon");
            var third2 = document.getElementById("scribeIcon");

            first2.style.borderColor = "transparent";
            second2.style.borderColor = "transparent";
            third2.style.borderColor = "transparent";
                classid.style.borderColor = "Aqua";
            alert("1");
            var classType = elementid.id;
                            alert("2");
            window.classType = classType;

        }
```

I've ran a little test and i have discovered that alert 1 triggers, but alert 2 does not... This is probably a simple mistake but I really can't see it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then check the error console. `elementid` is undefined (at least in the code you've shown us) or, if it is defined, is not an object with an `id` property.

Comment: Where do you define `elementid`?

Comment: Learn to use your console: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: you must devine all your variables at the top of your functions, it will help you avoid bugs like this + @epascarello have right, learn to use conlose :)

Answer (score 0):

if alert1 is triggering but not alert2, the problem must be that `elementid` is not defined and trying to access a property of an undefined variable will throw an error and break execution of your js. The solution:
a) make sure to define `elementid`
b) if you can't guarantee definition of `elementid`, add a check to see if it is defined before trying to access a child property.

A simple shorthand for this is `var classType = elementid && elementid.id;`

^ that's short for something like this:

```
var classType;
if(elementid) {
   classType = elementid.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of your element variable (first2, second2, third2, classid) is either null or undefined.  It is good defensive programming (especially in javascript) to check for null or undefined before using the variable.

I'm guessing when the showBorder2 function is called, the parameter passes to "classid" either is not a valid element or nothing is pass to it.